# Render conditional UI components within Shiny module based on input within the same module

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a module that conditionally renders ui components within the same module. The conditions are also contained in the same module. This conditional rendering is not working. Probably has something to do with scoping. I've added `ns <- session$ns` and wrapped inputs and outputs in the `renderUI` with `ns()`. Here is a minimum example. What am I missing? Besides code correction, some elaboration for better understanding would be much appreciated!

**ui.R**

```
#Define header
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Demo")

#Define sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Menu Item", tabName = "menu_item")))

#Define body
body <- dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(
    tabName = "menu_item",
    tabBox(
        width = 12,
        title = "",
        id = "tabset1",
        tabPanel(title = "Panel1",
                 panel1_ui("panel1")),
        tabPanel(title = "Panel 2")
    )
)))

#Create ui
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

**server.R**

```
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Server code for module
  callModule(panel1_server, "panel1")
  
}
```

**module.R**

```
#Define ui
panel1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(fluidRow(
    #Input box
    box(
      title = "Input box",
      status = "primary",
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      width = 4,
      
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "amount",
        label = "Amount:",
        min = 0,
        max = 5,
        value = 0,
        step = 1
      )
    ),
    
    conditionalPanel("input.amount > 0",
                     uiOutput(outputId = "output1"))
  ))
}

#Define server
panel1_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  fluidRow(column(width = 4,
                  
                  output$output1 <- renderUI({
                    box(
                      title = "Output box",
                      status = "primary",
                      width = 4,
                      solidHeader = TRUE,
                      uiOutput(outputId = ns("output2"))
                    )
                  })))
  
  output$output2 <- renderUI({
    if (ns(input$amount) == 0) {
      
    }
    else {
      lapply(c(1:input$amount), function(i) {
        hr()
        list(tags$u(strong(paste("Input ", i))),
             br(),
             column(
               6,
               dateInput(
                 inputId = paste0("date_", i),
                 label = paste0("Date:"),
                 value = Sys.Date()
               )
             ),
             column(
               6,
               selectInput(
                 inputId = paste0("yes_no", i),
                 label = "Yes or No:",
                 choices = c("Yes", "No"),
                 selected = "No"
               )
             ))
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: The `condition` argument in the `conditionalPanel` call is JavaScript.  JavaScript doesn't know about Shiny namespaces.  So you need to use the JavaScript id of the widget in the `condition`.  But, from personal experience, this is fragile.  I think you'd be better off using a `uiOutput` to create the panels rather than `conditionalPanel`.  You also have several problems in your module code.  Try getting an unconditional version to work before implementing the conditionality.

Comment: @Limey, thanks for your comment! I'll try to do it without conditions first and then try to add the conditionality without the `conditionalPanel` like you suggested. Will post that as a follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions by @Limey, I was able to break down the problem and solve it. Here is the working module code. I've added some comments where changes were made.

**module.R**

```
#Define ui
panel1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(fluidRow(
    #Input box
    box(
      title = "Input box",
      status = "primary",
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      width = 4,
      
      sliderInput(
        
        #Forgot to wrap amount in ns()
        inputId = ns("amount"), 
        label = "Amount:",
        min = 0,
        max = 5,
        value = 0,
        step = 1
      )
    ),
    
    #Removed conditionalPanel
    #Forgot to wrap output1 in ns()
    uiOutput(outputId = ns("output1")) 
  ))
}

#Define server
panel1_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  fluidRow(column(width = 4,
  
  output$output1 <- renderUI({
    
    #Removed ns() around input$amount
    #If condition is not true, render nothing
    #Otherwise, render box with content
    if (input$amount == 0) {}
    else {
      box(
        title = "Output box",
        status = "primary",
        width = 4,
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        
        #Removed ns() around input$amount
        lapply(c(1:input$amount), function(i) { 
        hr()
        list(tags$u(strong(paste("Input ", i))),
             br(),
             column(
               6,
               dateInput(
                 
                 #Forgot to wrap date_i in ns()
                 inputId = ns(paste0("date_", i)), 
                 label = paste0("Date:"),
                 value = Sys.Date()
               )
             ),
             column(
               6,
               selectInput(
                 
                 #Forgot to wrap yes_no_i in ns()
                 inputId = ns(paste0("yes_no", i)), 
                 label = "Yes or No:",
                 choices = c("Yes", "No"),
                 selected = "No"
               )
             ))
      }))
    }
  })
  ))
}
```